# Excel - copying text from column 1 and 2 to multiple times without deleting original content

Tags: excel

Basically I have the following:

2 columns, column-A contains Name and column-B contains Date

I need to copy the data from column 1 and place it at the end of the content in column 1 for the same ( eg A1 to A10 contains different names) without deleting original content.

I need to copy the data from column 2 and place it at the end of the content in column 2 for the same( eg B1 to B10 contains Same date and " 12-sep " for 10 different names) But here it should change to next day ( B11 to B20 another date "13-sep"  )

Comment: Are all the dates in **B1** thru **B10** the same??

Comment: Hi,Gary's thank you... Yes B1 thur B10 is same date(12-Sep) ... but next B11 thur B20 same date ( 13-Sep )...B21 thur B30 Same (14-Sep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
For I = 1 To 110 Step 10
    Range("A" & I & ":B" & I + 9).Copy Range("A" & I + 10)
    Range("B" & I + 10 & ":B" & I + 19).Value = Range("B" & I + 10).Value + 1
Next I
End Sub
```